# Fix a system error after UnTar in /data/data partition

Tags: partitions

I made a backup of app data in a rooted device with

`tar -czvf example.app.back.tar.gz /data/data/com.example.app/`

And after decompress the tar in other rooted devices with

```
cd /
tar -xvf example.app.back.tar.gz /data/data/com.example.app/
```

The app get this data working after I did

```
chmod -R 777 /data/data/com.example.app/
```

and when I reboot its like  a factory reset ,all the app data is gone and the apk that can be installed only in sd and when reboot again the app are deleted and the start wizard appears agains

I think that the tar command create a /data folder or mess in some way the mount points

Maybe I omit in the example some flags in the tar command that i originally typed

The destination device have Android 4.1.1

Comment: You didn't take care for the permissions. The app might have been assigned a different userID on the other device. No idea why you backup/restore like that – where `adb backup -noapk` (and its restore) would have addressed the same action in a more safe way.

Comment: Umm, isn't the title misleading? The body doesn't explain how the data partition became read only.

Comment: @Firelord that rigth I will change the title

Comment: @Izzy  How I fix permisions , i think I mess with the full /data

Comment: If it was just that single app: Uninstall it, remove that data folder (in case it remains). Then repeat backup/restore in a proper way: First install the app on the target device, then `adb restore` it's data from what you captured with `adb backup -noapk -f app_data.ab com.package.name` (where `com.package.name` is the app's package name – usually the same as the directory name you've dealt with before). If it broke more, factory-reset will be a last resort – especially if you really dealt "with the full `/data`".

Comment: @Izzi  I factory reset any times, when the table boots i install some apps and if i reboot this app are deleted, only let me install in the sdcard , app that can't be instaled in the sd  say that i have not space

Comment: What's your Android version? It's important.

Comment: @iBug The device have Android 4.1.1

Comment: What's your actual question? What is the desired end state?

Answer (score 0):

Well, good job for running `chmod` after untar-ing. You, however, missed the most important thing: **file owner/group**.

If you look into `/data/system/uiderrors.txt`, you'll find a bunch of information like this:

```
1970/01/01 00:00: Package jackpal.androidterm uid has changed from 0 to 10001, old data erased.
```

[I've already answered a question before](/a/172163) about Android applications' UIDs. A factory reset would have made you lose more data than you have already lost now. As [Izzy pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180458/#comment232102_180458), you didn't take care about file <s>permission</s> owner/group, as *the app might have been assigned a different UID on the other device*, and all its data were erased by Package Installer.

You may want to take a look at my answer and restore file owner from `/data/system/packages.list` manually. As far as I can tell everything will be fine after that.